# Showing callout in mkmapview without title and only with UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have custom `MKAnnotation` where i'm implementing `title()` method of `MKAnnotation` protocol. My requirement is to have callout only with button and no title. But the problem is I get callout with title and button only if I implement title() method. If string returned is nil i don't see callout bubble. Please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, its a little hackish but it works.
set the title to be @" " (empty space) just to make the callout pop and then you can wrap your button with a view, and add the button as a subview with origin.x of whatever center is...

```
MKPinAnnotationView* view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Null"];
view.canShowCallout = YES;
view.clipsToBounds = NO;

UIView * v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
v.clipsToBounds = NO;
v.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

UITextField* field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-42, 0, 100, 30)];
field.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
field.clipsToBounds = NO;
field.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
field.delegate = self;
[v addSubview:field];

view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = v;
```

this example is with a UITextField but it will also work with your button.

Answer (score 0):

Use : `[YourAnotationView setCanShowCallout:NO];`

Comment: By doing this it completely hide callout, but my requirement is i want have callout with button and no title

Comment: Ok then you can leave the title nil or an empty string like @"".

Comment: Returning nil or @"" doesnot pop the callout.Instead returning @" " gives callout but with preceding space, which shoulnt be there.